# How do I make the button that fired off the modal popup stay in a hover state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have several icons on a page that when clicked fire off a modal popup.  Is there a way to make that icon stay in hover state after the modal is activated and then go back to an off-state when the modal is closed?

I thought I could do it with OnMouseOver and Onclick but that doesn't do the job. I need a way so when the modal pops up on the side you know what icon you clicked.

```
<a href="#myModal6" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/img/button_dots-white.svg" onMouseOver="this.src='assets/img/button_dots-orange.svg'" onMouseOut="this.src='assets/img/button_dots-white.svg'" height="30px" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant get this done using an onclick-event because your onmouseleave-events gets fired after your onclick-event and its setting it back to the default. but if you use a div with a background-image you could do it like i did here:

```css
.button-img {
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=');
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

.button-img:hover {
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAMLCwgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.active {
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAMLCwgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==') !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myModal6" data-toggle="modal">
  <div class="button-img" onclick="this.classList.add('active');"></div>
</a>
```

if you want to get rid of the active-state you only have to use `yourElement.classList.remove('active');` at any time you want to.